# PHP Syntax issue with headers

Tags: php, syntax

Can't seem to get it right with the syntax:

```
<?php 
if isset $_POST['tutorial'] {
    header('Location: /phonebooks?tutorial=1b');
} else {
    header('Location: /phonebooks?phonebook_created=1');
};
?>
```

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: This is basic syntax. You should really read up on it before continuing trying to code in PHP, in my opinion. It will make things go much more smoothly later on.

Answer (score 3):

You're missing brackets around your if condition and around `$_POST['tutorial']`, which is an argument to `isset`. It should be:

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['tutorial']))
{
  header('Location: /phonebooks?tutorial=1b');
}
else
{
  header('Location: /phonebooks?phonebook_created=1');
}
?>
```

As pointed out in the comments, an absolute URL is required for a `Location` header as well (so instead of `/phonebooks?tutorial=1b`, you'd need to specify `http(s)://yourdomain.com/phonebooks?tutorial=1b`).

Comment: And `Location:` headers should, according to the RFC, be full URIs (i.e., they should start with `http://` or `https://`.

Comment: Are brackets really necessary for a single condition `if` statement? It's been a while since I've whipped out the PHP skills.

Comment: @Anthony Yes, brackets are required around the conditions for all the php keywords that take conditions (`if`, `for`, `while`, etc.)

Answer (score 3):

Ok, first off, you need to use parenthesis.  Multiple parenthesis.

The first set need to go around the contents of the if construct:

```
if ( ... ) {
```

The second set need to go around the `isset()` function call:

```
isset($_POST['tutorial'])
```

So that line becomes:

```
if (isset($_POST['tutorial'])) {
```

You also have another problem.  Don't use location headers with relative urls.  It's against the HTTP specification.  Always use absolute URLs, otherwise you may break some webservers (I know IIS hates it), or browsers...